# Programmatically add the argument to a paragraph view

Tags: views, paragraphs

We're using paragraphs on a Drupal 8.8.5 with paragraphs 8.x-1.11.

To help relieve some data entry, I've created a module that auto-populate a custom content type, `Student Page`. This content type has a paragraphs field, and for this auto-generated content, we want to attach a custom paragraph type, `Student Gallery`, which has a views entity reference. The contextual argument to filter the view display is the student's email address, so I want to populate that field automatically in my module.

[image]

I can get the node to generate correctly with all of the fields, except I'm not sure how to populate the argument field of the view.

```
  $paragraph = Paragraph::create([
    'type' => 'gallery_student',
    'field_gallery_title' => $student . '\'s work',
  ]);
  $paragraph->save();

  $node = Node::create([
    'type'             => 'student_page',
    'field_paragraphs' => $paragraph,
  ]);

  $node->save();
```

The field on the paragraph is called `field_gallery2_view_ref` and its type is "Views Reference". The "View display plugins to allow" is only set to allow "Embed".

How do I programmatically set this argument?

Comment: This is not a good idea. First, you shouldn't use paragraphs for a static structure of a content type. Second, you shouldn't replicate field data in the argument field. Normally such a gallery belongs in a block. If you need to attach it to a content type then try https://www.drupal.org/project/eva, which has full token support for views arguments.

Comment: @4k4 I don't disagree with you, but I don't make the decisions, the content creators and editors do. This gallery is for student graduation and is going live next week-- I'm trying to keep these people from working over the entire weekend.